# Uploading a file to a bucket in Amazon S3 failing with "Maximum number of retry attempts reached"

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-s3

I have been trying to create buckets and upload files to Amazon S3 using their .net SDK.
I am able to create the buckets and specify that they be created in the EU region. The code used to create the buckets is as below

```
PutBucketRequest request = new PutBucketRequest();
request.WithBucketName(bucketName)
       .WithBucketRegion(S3Region.EU);

client.PutBucket(request);
```

I then proceed to upload a file to the bucket using the following code:

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
request.WithBucketName(bucketName)
    .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
    .WithKey(remoteFileName)
    .WithInputStream(uploadFileStream);
```

The file upload code fails with the error "Maximum retry attempts reached."

Can anyone let me know what else I need to be doing in order for the upload to work?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** Trying to upload a file to the same bucket using the AWS Management Console works fine.

Answer (score 13):

I found the issue, at last.

When targeting buckets in a specific region, the Amazon S3 client object will have to be configured to use a specific endpoint. The code to configure the endpoint is as in the constructor and creation of the client is in the individual methods of the class below:

```
public class AmazonS3Service : IAmazonS3Service 
{
     private AmazonS3 client;
     private string accessKeyID;
     private string secretAccessKeyID;
     private AmazonS3Config config;

     public AmazonS3Service()
     {
         accessKeyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
         secretAccessKeyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
         config = new AmazonS3Config();
         config.ServiceURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSEUEndPoint"];
      }

    public void CreateBucket(string bucketName)
    {
        using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID, config))
        {
            try
            {
                PutBucketRequest request = new PutBucketRequest();
                request.WithBucketName(bucketName)
                       .WithBucketRegion(S3Region.EU);

                 client.PutBucket(request);
             }
             catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
             {
                if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null && (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                {
                //log exception - ("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                }
                else
                {
                //log exception - ("An Error, number {0}, occurred when creating a bucket with the message '{1}", amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode, amazonS3Exception.Message);    
                }
            }
        }
    }

     public void UploadFile(string bucketName, Stream uploadFileStream, string remoteFileName)
    {
        using (client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(accessKeyID, secretAccessKeyID, config))
        {
            try
            {
                PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
                request.WithBucketName(bucketName)
                    .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
                    .WithKey(remoteFileName)
                    .WithInputStream(uploadFileStream);

                 using (S3Response response = client.PutObject(request))
                 {
                    WebHeaderCollection headers = response.Headers;
                    foreach (string key in headers.Keys)
                    {
                        //log headers ("Response Header: {0}, Value: {1}", key, headers.Get(key));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (AmazonS3Exception amazonS3Exception)
            {
                if (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode != null && (amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidAccessKeyId") || amazonS3Exception.ErrorCode.Equals("InvalidSecurity")))
                {
                //log exception - ("Please check the provided AWS Credentials.");
                }
                else
                {
                //log exception -("An error occurred with the message '{0}' when writing an object", amazonS3Exception.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

The various endpoints of each of Amazon's services can be found at at this URL - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/index.html?rande.html

Hope this helps someone!