# Backand's API with S3: Upload to region other than US Standard

Tags: amazon-s3, backand

I would like to use AWS S3 to store my app's user's files securely.

I am based in the EU (UK), so my bucket's region is EU (Ireland). Based on the Noterious example in the [Backand docs](http://docs.backand.com/en/latest/scenarios/amazon/index.html), and the snippet provided by the Backand dashboard, this is my custom File Upload action:

```
function backandCallback(userInput, dbRow, parameters, userProfile) {

  var data = {
    "key" : "<my AWS key ID", 
    "secret" : "<my secret key>", 
    "filename" : parameters.filename, 
    "filedata" : parameters.filedata,         
    "region" : "Ireland",
    "bucket" : "<my bucket name>"
  };
  var response = $http({method:"PUT",url:CONSTS.apiUrl + "/1/file/s3" , 
           data: data, headers: {"Authorization":userProfile.token}});

  return response;
}
```

When testing the action in the Backand dashboard, I get this error: `417 The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.: An error occurred, please try again or contact the administrator. Error details: Maximum number of retry attempts reached : 3`.

With an American bucket and `region: "US Standard"`, it works without error. So, similarly to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405291/uploading-a-file-to-a-bucket-in-amazon-s3-failing-with-maximum-number-of-retry), I think this is because the AWS endpoint isn't correctly set up.

I have tried `region: "EU"`, `region: "Ireland"`, `region: "eu-west-1"` and similar combinations.

So - Is there any way to configure Backand to use AWS endpoints other than `US Standard`? (I'd have thought that would have been the whole point of setting the `region`.)

Comment: `s3-eu-west-1` perhaps? That's the wrong answer to "region" but then again, "US Standard" is pretty ridiculous...  but the regional REST endpoint is `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` which is why it might be worth trying this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Michael-sqlbot, but that hasn't worked either. I'll get on to the Backand team.

Comment: When you find it, please post an answer here, for the benefit of future visitors.  Answering your own question is perfectly valid if you genuinely find your own answer to a real question.

Answer (score 1):

We have checked this issues and apparently there is a different in the security method of AWS between east coast (N. Virginia) and newer regions like Ireland.
This issue is scheduled for one of the next releases, and I will update here when resolved.

Comment: Hi @Itay. I'm coming back to this after a while. Did this ever get resolved?